# Have lived or lived?

Tags: past-tense

I was preparing answers for the speaking part of the IELTS exam. I used the Past Simple like this "many famous people lived in my country such as
..." (I am talking about the people who died and were famous) but the sentence seems wrong. Can I use the Past Simple without referring to any specific time or shiuld I use Present Perfect?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with either tense. There are many different specific phrases and tenses that could convey the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, saying "have lived" could potentially assume the famous people didn't die in your country. If they did live and die there, then you might say they "lived" there. If they only lived there for a short while before leaving and living somewhere else, you might say the "have lived" there.